# Parse JSON string in AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, ampscript, json, gtl

We are currently passing a string attribute via the REST API that contains JSON.

```
{ "User_List": "[{\"name\":\"john doe\", \"email\":\"john.doe@mail.com\"}, {\"name\":\"jane doe\", \"email\":\"jane.doe@mail.com\"}]" }
```

We then use server side JavaScript to parse the attribute string value into JSON.

```
<script runat=server>

  Platform.Load("Core","1");

  var userList    = Platform.Recipient.GetAttributeValue("User_List");
  var userListObj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(userList);

</script>
```

We then later use that JSON to build a dynamic list from the JSON data.

```
<p>
  <script runat=server>
    Write("<ul>");

    for (var i = 0; i < userListObj.length; i++) {
      Write("<li>" + userListObj[i].name + ", " + userListObj[i].email + "</li>");
    }

    Write("</ul>");
  </script> 
</p>
```

My question is, is there a way to do this via AMPscript?  I couldn't find anything about parsing a string into JSON via AMPscript.

Answer (score 1):

So I may have not asked the correct question for what I was trying to accomplish.  This worked for me. Passing Recipient_List as a JSON string attribute.

```
"[{\"name\":\"john doe\",\"email\":\"john.doe@mail.com\"},{\"name\":\"jane doe\",\"email\":\"jane.doe@mail.com\"}]"
```

With the JSON string input shown above.

```
%%[
   var @json
   set @json = AttributeValue("Recipient_List")
]%%

{{.dataobject JsonVar type=variable source=@json maxrows=20}}
   {{.data}}
        {"target":"@Json"}
   {{/data}}
{{/dataobject}}
{{#each JsonVar}}
   <p>{{name}}, {{email}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no JSON parsing functions in AMPScript.  Most of the parsing I've seen is for XML, since AMPScript has several XML parsing functions.

Talk to anyone at SFMC they'll steer you away from using SSJS in the platform.  It's slow and very resource intensive.  It's incredibly helpful in landing pages, but once you start mentioning it in email, they'll advise against it.

You can use AMPScript for most everything -- aside from arrays and things like parsing JSON.

There's more discussion here: [Include JSON Feed in an Email](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/101676/include-json-feed-in-an-email)

**Update**

Here's a simple [GTL](https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/guide_template_language/parsing_json/dataobject_tag_examples/) example as [@Tim Reynolds](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/28481/tim-reynolds) suggested.

```
%%[

var @Json
set @Json = '[{"name": "john doe","email": "john.doe@mail.com"},{"name": "jane doe","email": "jane.doe@mail.com"}]'

]%%
{{.dataobject JsonVar type=variable source=@Json maxrows=20}}
     {{.data}}
          {"target":"@Json"}
     {{/data}}
{{/dataobject}}
{{#each JsonVar}}
  <br><br>Name: {{name}}
  <br>Email: {{email}}
{{/each}}
```

**Output**

```
Name: john doe 
Email: john.doe@mail.com 

Name: jane doe 
Email: jane.doe@mail.com
```

Comment: This is something I am working on right now, and I hope you are wrong because I am counting on using AMPScript to parse JSON. This page directly mentions AMPScript but is under GTScript heading... https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/guide_template_language/parsing_json/datasource_tag_examples/

Comment: You may be correct.  Mixing AMPScript and GTL may be the best route to take.  I've generally poo-poo'd GTL since it doesn't work on Landing Pages/Microsites.

Comment: Copied this code verbatim and received the following error. Any ideas?
The data source referenced by a Guide Each tag was not found.
 DataSourceIDType: Unspecified
 DataSourceID: JsonVar
 Guide Tag: {{#each JsonVar}}
 Tag Index: 7761

Comment: It appears the issues is only when using the code within a content block on a Content Builder template. Works fine in HTML paste.