# Retrieving and parsing JSON from a data extension row using AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, json, dataextensions

I have no idea where to begin with this (have tried many things from this exchange but nothing works - probably because I am messing it up) but basically I have a JSON array being stored in a cell under one field called 'campaign' in our sendable data extension. This is coming via our REST API.

Is it possible then to take this array and parse it and loop it to display the information within to the customer? We basically want to show the customer which markets they signed up for and the budget for each market (the number of markets can change depending on customer)

This is so far the information in the field "campaign"

```
{
    "url": "http://trivago.com/hotelmanager/",
    "campaign_markets": [
        {
            "market_name": "Germany",
            "budget": "500"
        },
        {
            "market_name": "Austria",
            "budget": "599"
        },
        {
            "market_name": "United Kingdom",
            "budget": "500"
        }
    ]
}
```

We also have the fields SubscriberKey and Emailaddress.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a lot of answers related to this, that should help you solve what you are trying to do:

- [Parse JSON string in AMPscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/107133/parse-json-string-in-ampscript)
- [Can AMPScript parse JSON?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34945/can-ampscript-parse-json?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Json parse in emails with ampscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/116477/json-parse-in-emails-with-ampscript?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But i think the best walkthrough is found on [Adam Spriggs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5202/adam-spriggs) github site:
https://gist.github.com/wvpv/aa9580f976c85c425761385d088d024f